# How to configure webpack to only bundle files within a directory?

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack

I've a folder structure for my project that looks roughly like this:

```
myproject
|-- some-folder
|   `-- src
|       `-- index.tsx
|-- src
|   |-- components
|   |   `-- files.tsx
|   `-- index.tsx
`-- webpack.config.js
```

When I run webpack, it tries to bundle the `index.tsx` file in both `src` and `some-folder`.

This would then throw an error because the `index.tsx` file in `some-folder` has certain dependencies webpack cannot resolve since is not meant to be bundled together.

This is how I've configured my webpack's entry point:

```
var config = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: {
       app: './index.tsx'
    }
}
```

How can I configure webpack to only look for files within the `src` folder and not else where unless I define another different full path in the entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that this is pretty old, it might be solved already, but was it something to do with adding an "exclude" statement to make sure the "/some-folder" was omitted?